# What's wrong with this conky config? It's dog slow and doesn't display most of the text

Tags: text, configure, conky

It looks fine other than that it runs very slowly and I don't get any text beyond the 9th line or so. Window is the right size. I've got this feeling like Conky is the wrong tool for this. For the record, I want it transparent after I get it figured out.

```
text_buffer_size 2048

background yes
double_buffer yes

alignment top_right

draw_borders no
draw_outline no
draw_shades no

gap_x 0
gap_y 0
out_to_console no
out_to_stderr no
extra_newline no

own_window yes
own_window_type normal
own_window_transparent no
own_window_colour 000000
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_argb_value 128
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager

minimum_size 1465 720
maximum_width 1465
maximum_height 720

uppercase no
use_spacer none

use_xft yes
xftalpha 0.1
xftfont Droid Sans:size=9

color1 light blue
color2 aquamarine

TEXT
${color1}
/development/jboss/log/all-server.log:
${execp /usr/bin/tail -n 131 -f /development/jboss/log/all-server.log | sed 's/^/\$\{color2\}/' | sed -e 's/exception\|error\|denied\|failed\|failing\|failure\|fail/\$\{color red\}&$\{color2\}/I' }
```

Comment: Well I did. I'm new to conky. So what you're telling me, then, is that Conky is probably the wrong tool for the job. Color me disappointed. Seems like there's no good tools for doing this anymore. Minor correction: tail -f prints new entries from the log rather than to it.

Comment: Polling doesn't seem to be what I want though, as some lines might not even cross the screen in that case.